# Trying to use Powershell to format Excel spreadsheet with parentheses as negative numbers

Tags: excel, powershell, formatting, numbers

I am very  new to Powershell and am trying to convert the data I have in excel from negative numbers into numbers with parentheses.  Can someone help me?

For example, -4,414,757 in cell A1 I want to be (4,414,757).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the number format of the cell to General.

```
$ExcelWorksheet.Cells("A1").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"
```

Comment: Thanks @BigBen.  Updated.